# how to implement this pattern using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm new to using JSP and need to figure out how to do this. I'd appreciate any pointers on how to do this ?

I need to display images in this table-like structure. To simplify the problem,

```
A  B  C
D  E  F
G  H  I
```

where each of these elements are a part of the Set names in action class.

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>(0);

names.add("A");
names.add("B");
names.add("C");
names.add("D");
names.add("E");
names.add("F");
names.add("G");
names.add("H");
names.add("I");
```

Its fairly trivial to do it in java, however, I am having a hard time to figure out, how do I ask the iterator to point to next element manually.

```
<s:iterator value="names">
 <s:property/>
 I'd now like to point iterator to point to next or run a nested iterator loop here.
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish it with JSTL:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach items="names" var="name" varStatus="i">
            <c:if test="${!i.first && !i.last && i.index % 3 == 0}">
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </c:if>
            <td><c:out value="${name}" /></td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Doing so, a new line (`</tr><tr>`) will be added every 3 elements.

(not tested)

Comment: You need it otherwise you end up having an empty line at the end

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSTL [forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) loop. You can find a number of examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/JSTLForEachLoop.htm).

Comment: is there a way to do something like this: iterator = iterator.next() ?

Comment: @brainydexter - I am not sure if I understand what you are asking by iterator. If you would rather use Java collection iterator instead of JSTL loops then you can embed the java code as scriptlet. However, I highly recommend to not do so. What's your concern regarding JSTL loops? It is the standard way to iterate collections in a JSP.

Comment: My apologies. I come from a c++ background and tend to think like that. I was looking for nested loops or a way to refer to the "next" element. I figured you can't refer to the next element, just like that. satoshi's answer is very near to what I ended up using.

Comment: another quick q: is it recommended for or against to mix jsp tags with jstl tags ?

Answer (score 0):

As CoolBeans said, you can use JSTL forEach loop.

If you'd like to see an example of that (alongside other good JSTL examples), check out [JSTL Examples](http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/Java/jstl-examples.html).

"Iterating over data structures" has some info and examples on what you're trying to do.